# can't load simple-html-dom class two times in one class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

When I try to load the file in a dom object for the secont time(i clear it befor), the dom variable is empty :(
How can I use simple-html-dom class for two times in my class?

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
class RO{
    public $dom;
    public $dom2;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $this->dom2 = new simple_html_dom();
    }
    function GetDatumInUroPodatkovInTabKrajev($lang){
        $this->dom->load_file("http://www...diferentadresthenbelow...html");
        $tabelaTempInKrajev = $this->dom->find('table[@class="online"]');

        //some code...

        //some code...

        return $this->functon2("minkjaaa");
    }
    function functon2($ik){
        $this->dom2->load_file("http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/vreme_si.html");
        $tabelaVremRazm = $this->dom2->find('table[@class="online"]');    // this line trows an error, becaus dom2 is empty
        return"";
    }
}
?>
```

and the trowen error:
`[Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\..\simple_html_dom.php on line ..]`

Comment: Try `table.online` instead... also you said you cleared the first object, where and how ?

Comment: I delete it with "$this->dom->clear();", but if I use this or not is the same...

Comment: and tnx for the table.online tip ! :) but it's still not working :/

Comment: now your tip helped me alot thx agen!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find("SELECTORS", index)` Find returns an array of objects unless an optional index is specified, then it will return the Nth object... This is probably what you're missing... Here's a working example:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$url = "http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/vreme_si.html";

//Create a DOM object
$dom2 = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$dom2->load_file($url);


// Find the link with the appropriate selectors
$table = $dom2->find('table.online', 0);


// Find succeeded
if ($table)
    echo $table->outertext;
else
    echo "Find function failed !";


// Clear DOM object (needed essentially when using many)
$dom2->clear(); 
unset($dom2);
```

[Online DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/73e-k44)

Comment: Tnx for that :) but the find still throws an error :/


[Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\....\simple_html_dom.php on line ..]

The problem arises when I try to use(load_file) for the second time, and I can't solve that ://

Comment: Try `$html= file_get_contents('http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/vreme_si.html');` then `$this->dom2->load($html);`